# Databinding problems with postback

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, page-lifecycle

I've two issues currently preventing me from finishing two projects properly. I'll put them both here as I believe they're connected to the asp.net page lifecycle, but I can't find a way around them.

First I have a DropDownList which I must sort in codebehind. It only contains text, so I should be able to do that with the following method called in page load:

```
        Dim alist As ArrayList = New ArrayList

        For Each litem As ListItem In ltEsittelyDropDownList.Items
            alist.Add(litem.Text)
        Next

        alist.Sort()

        Dim uusiDDList As New DropDownList

        For i As Integer = 0 To alist.Count - 1
            Dim litem As New ListItem
            litem.Text = alist(i).ToString
            litem.Value = alist(i).ToString
            uusiDDList.Items.Add(litem)

            ' Response.Write(alist(i).ToString)
        Next

        ltEsittelyDropDownList = uusiDDList
        ltEsittelyDropDownList.DataBind()
```

As you can see, there's a commented response.write in there, which shows the list is actually sorted. So why, when I load the page, can't I see any effect?

The other problem, which is more critical and difficult, is as follows:

In the aspx page I'm binding a SQL Server 2005 datasource to a gridview. And in the code-behind I catch on to the RowDataBound event in which I handle some links and properties inside the gridviews' cells. But I cannot get this to work on the first page load, only after the first extra postback.

So, what is there to do? And thanks for all advice in front!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is calling DataBind on a control you have filled manually.  You likely have a DataSource specified in the control declaration, which is being used when DataBind is called.  You can simplify the code by just adding the list items to the original control:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To alist.Count - 1
    ltEsittelyDropDownList.Items.Add(New ListItem(alist(i).ToString())
Next
```

Alternatively, as you have a collection already, you can just bind it to the control:

```
ltEsittelyDropDownList.DataSource = alist
ltEsittelyDropDownList.DataBind()
```

For your second problem, some example code would help - specifically, where and how the control is databound and the code in RowDataBound.

Comment: Heh, some mistake. Used your first suggestion and it worked fine. Thanks a bunch!